# "How many numbers exist which are less than or equal to n and are divisible by a, b or c?"

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics

First line contains 't' denoting the number of test cases. Next t lines contain 4 integers denoting n, a, b and c separated by spaces.

Sample input:

> 1
>   15 2 3 5

Output:

> 11

Constraints:

- \$1 \le t \le 10^5\$
- \$1 \le n\le 10^9\$
- \$1\le a,b,c \le 10^5\$

I have written this code which is working fine for smaller numbers. For large number, timeout is happening. Could you please help me to optimize this solution?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DivisibilityoOfNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int T = s.nextInt();
        for(int t_i=0; t_i<T; t_i++)
        {
            //long t = s.nextLong();
            long n = s.nextLong();
            long a = s.nextLong();
            long b = s.nextLong();
            long c = s.nextLong();

            long out_ = divisibilty(a, c, b, n);
            System.out.println(out_);
         }

         wr.close();
         s.close();
    }
    static long FindLCM(long a, long b)
    {
        return (a * b) / new BigInteger(a+"").gcd(new BigInteger(b+"")).intValue();
    }
    static long divisibilty(long a, long c, long b, long n){

        long lcmAB = FindLCM(a, b);
        long lcmAC = FindLCM(a, c);
        long lcmBC = FindLCM(c, b);

        long a_divisor = n / a ;
        long b_divisor = n / b;
        long c_divisor = n / c;

        long common_divisorA = n / lcmAB;
        long common_divisorB = n / lcmAC;
        long common_divisorC = n / lcmBC;

        long ans = a_divisor + b_divisor + c_divisor-(common_divisorA+common_divisorB +common_divisorC);

        return ans;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens for larger numbers then? Memory problem? Timeout? Wrong result because it overflows? Other problem?

Comment: This code is broken.  It won't work for inputs like `30 2 3 5`.  In general, it won't work for any input where `n >= LCM(LCM(a, b), c)`.  A simple example of a bad input is `6 1 2 3`.  Obviously it should return 6 (every number is divisible by at least one of 1, 2, or 3 because every number is divisible by 1).  This code will actually return `6 + 3 + 2 - (3 + 2 + 1)` or 5.  Not a large input error, but a simple logic error.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: Timeout is happening for large number(time limit for one test case is 1 sec).

Comment: @mdfst13:Thanks to point this logical flaw . even if I resolved this it will fail for large number. do you suggest me better approach

Comment: Its from ongoing contest on hackerrank, You are not supposed to ask such question here.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh According to Hackerrank maybe it's not. According to us it is fine. We have had discussion on our meta about this before and the conclusion was that it's up to each one if they want to post it and if they want to read the solutions posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     static long FindLCM(long a, long b)
>     {
>         return (a * b) / new BigInteger(a+"").gcd(new BigInteger(b+"")).intValue();
>     }
> ```

A simple optimization here would be to convert to `BigInteger` before calling this.  You call it multiple times with each value.

```
    static long findLCM(long a, long b, final BigInteger A, final BigInteger B) {
        return (a * b) / A.gcd(B).longValue();
    }
```

This way you don't have to repeatedly convert long values to strings and then to `BigInteger` values.

In Java, the standard is to start method names with a lower case letter.

In two of three methods, you put the `{` on the same line as the method declaration.  In this one, you put it on a separate line. The Java standard is same line, but more importantly, you should be consistent.

When converting from `long` to `BigInteger`, the most efficient way is to use `valueOf`:

```
final BigInteger A = BigInteger.valueOf(long a);
```

Converting from a `String` is less efficient in and of itself.  Having to convert to a `String` first makes it worse.

But this leads to a bigger question.  Why a `BigInteger` if you are just going to take the `intValue` at the end?  Even switching to `longValue` still leaves that question.

The obvious answer is that you wanted the `BigInteger` `gcd` implementation.  It's not clear why though. It's not like it's more efficient than other implementations.  If I had to guess, this is likely to be the real problem.  So write your own `gcd` and use that instead.  There are plenty of examples on the internet.

```
public static long gcd(log a, long b) {
    while ( 0 != b ) {
        long temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp % b;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Which you'd use like

```
    static long findLCM(long a, long b) {
        return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
    }
```

This just uses primitives, which will be more efficient than `BigInteger` math.

When doing these challenges, I see a lot of people use `BufferedReader` and read all the input prior to doing any calculations or output.  You may want to do some testing to see if that helps.